# Determine if string is valid XML in Postgres

Tags: regex, xml, postgresql

I have a text field in a table that contains JSON data as well as XML data. As I want to work with XML data only if it's valid XML, I want a way to make sure I can cast the string as XML without producing an error when `'{"key":"val"}'::XML` is possible.

Basically I want a function `select isxml('{"key":"val"})` to return `false`, and `select isxml('<key>1</key>')` to be `true`.

I checked existing Postgres functions such as xml_is_well_formed, but they still return true when checking JSON strings. Maybe I can catch the error and deal with it in exceptions after a bad cast? Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: An earlier response from someone pointed towards a regex solution, but unfortunately did not work exactly as expected. I'm not sure how the regex should be modified here but it should be possible.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jLrF3VmKpVE7Mbqeo8r2VY/0

Comment: The second response now works for part of the original issue, I am now able to distinguish XML from JSON by testing if string can be casted as JSON. However, the non JSON string can still be any other non XML string. The question remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use the `xml_is_well_formed` together with a function that checks whether or not the text content is a valid json. I.e.:

```
create or replace function is_valid_json(content text)
  returns boolean
as
$$
begin
  return (content::json is not null);
exception 
  when others then
     return false;  
end;
```

And in your query, you do `[...] xml_is_well_formed(content) and not is_valid_json(content) [...]`.

Comment: This would work fine to rule out bad xml and json strings, but would include random strings of neither types. e.g.  `SELECT xml_is_well_formed('abc') and not is_valid_json('abc')` would return true when it really shouldn't.
Maybe regex is required? I expected Postgres to have something built in for this.

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution is as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isjson(p_json text)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
begin
  perform (p_json::json is not null);
  return 1;
exception 
  when others then
     return 0;  
end;
$function$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isxml(p_xml text)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
BEGIN
    PERFORM (p_xml::XML IS NOT NULL);
    IF (xml_is_well_formed(p_xml) 
        AND NOT (CASE WHEN isjson(p_xml) = 1 THEN TRUE ELSE false END) 
        AND (SELECT p_xml ~ '^<.*>') )THEN      -- regex matches <>, this may have uncovered edge cases
        RETURN true;
    ELSE 
        RETURN false;
    END IF;

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN false;  
END;
$function$;
```

Note: my isjson function returns integer due to other legacy compatibility reasons, it would be easier to use boolean for this specific case. This should rule out most problematic cases but have lots of limitations in the regex used, accepting suggestions for improvement.